# Use array instead of object in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have the following var:

```
    filter =  {
            "country": 1,
            "Age Group": {},
            "Gender": {},
            "NEWSEC": {},
            "Telco_Segment": {}
    };
```

and function:

```
function facetBuilder(key, val)
{
    if(key == 'country')
    {   
        filter.country = val;
    }
    else
    {
        if(typeof filter[key][val] !== "undefined" )
        {
            delete filter[key][val]; //I'm assuming you want to remove it
        }
        else
        {
            filter[key][val] = true;
        }
    }

    console.log(filter);
}
```

The resulting object ends up looking something like this:

```
    filter =  {
            "country": 1,
            "Age Group": {
                4: true,
                3: true,
                2: true
            },
            "Gender": {
                1: true
            },
            "NEWSEC": {
                3: true,
                2: true
            },
            "Telco_Segment": {}
    };
```

but what I really want is something like this:

```
    filter =  {
            "country": 1,
            "Age Group": [4,3,2],
            "Gender": [1],
            "NEWSEC": [3,2],
            "Telco_Segment": []
    };
```

And I'm not sure how to approach it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of

```
filter[key][val] = true;
```

how about

```
filter[key].push(val);
```

and

```
filter =  {
    "country": 1,
    "Age Group": [],
                 ^^---empty array, instead of {} for object.
```

Comment: And it was that simple... Thank you!

Comment: You'll also have to change `delete filter[key][val];` to `var a = filter[key]; delete a[a.indexOf(val)];`.

Comment: @MindVirus: Using `delete` to remove array elements is not a good idea. Using `.splice` is better.

Comment: Neither my original method of removing the value from the array works properly, nor the method provided by MindVirus.

Answer (score 0):

What you have now, `if(typeof filter[key][val] !== "undefined" )`, is good, because objects have constant-time lookups. If you use an array scan, `if(filter[key].indexOf(val) !== -1)`, the time complexity increases to O(n) because you'd have to scan each element to see if it's in the array.